# Generate a random char, oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with a column like:
A1
A2
.
.
B1
..
B7

I need to generate this column randomly. This column type is CHAR(2). I tried using TRUNC(dbms_random.value(65,67)) and then ascii function for the letter part of the char but it has not worked. Can you please help me generate A1-A7, B1-B7 randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `CHR` funciton instead of `ASCII`, this should work:

```
   CHR(TRUNC(dbms_random.value(65,67)))  -- A..B
|| CHR(TRUNC(dbms_random.value(49,56)))  -- 1..7
```